# Is it normal for fields on the read database not to appear in the write database?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Is it normal for the CQRS write database to contain different fields to the CQRS Read database? For example, in the case above, then is it normal for `Product.Description` to be persisted on the read side (NoSQL) but not on the write side (SQL Server)?

I realize that the database of choice on the write side (RDBMS) may structure data differently to the database of choice on the read side (NoSQL). I am specifically asking if it is "allowed" to choose what data fields are persisted on the read side and the write side.

The reason I ask is that a book I am reading implies this is normal, however, I cannot find any examples in the book or online that support this.

Please see the code below:

```
public class Product
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public void LookupDescriptionByCode(List<ProductDescriptionLookup> productCodes)
        {
            Description = productCodes.Find(x => x.Code == Code).Description;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it normal for the CQRS write database to contain different fields to the CQRS Read database?

Usually, the write database will be a superset (bigger than) the read database.

> is it normal for Product.Description to be persisted on the read side (NoSQL) but not on the write side (SQL Server)?

No, but maybe.

If you imagine a system with a monolithic write database, then the "book of record" would be the write database, and everything would live there; the read database would just be cached copies of the information in the write database.

But if you were to break up that monolith, the read model might combine information from multiple write models.  So the write model might only know about the product code, but the read model might have the product description (because it used the code to look up the description from "somewhere else").

But *somewhere* in the system you have an official copy of what "the" product code is at any given time.

> I have an event log, which is the book of record. I am confused why a write database is needed as well. I can see the benefit of persisting certain domain objects to the write database, however not all of them?

If you are doing event sourcing, then your event log is usually stored in your write database (which might be an RDBMS, or might be a dedicated message store).

> Is it fair to say that if there is an EventStore/EventLog/IntegrationLog then a write database (relational tables for each domain object) is not needed.

I think its far to say that if your event store is acting as the book of record, you don't need relational tables to *also* act as a book of record for those same entities.

It could make sense, for example, that you use event sourcing for part of your domain, but not all of it.  Or you might want to cache representations to improve the efficiency of your writes.  Or...

Comment: I have an event log, which is the book of record.  I am confused why a write database is needed as well.  I can see the benefit of persisting certain domain objects to the write database, however not all of them?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. +1. Is it fair to say that if there is an EventStore/EventLog/IntegrationLog then a write database (relational tables for each domain object) is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the most recent edit.  Finally what if I am using an Event Log (integration log) instead of an Event Store.  Is it advisable to have relational tables as well - in my case they are not needed because records never change after they are entered.  I believe I am doing CQRS without event sourcing and with an integration log.